# jinja2 escape joined character in joinee

Tags: python, jinja2

I am rendering a template with jinja2. I have a list like

```
favorits = ['cho|colate', 'cookies', 'steak']
```

which I want rendered as

```
cho\|colate | cookies | steak
```

for asciidoc processing.
If `'cho|colate`' did not have the `|` which I want escaped with a backslash, it would be very easy:

```
{{ favorits | join(' | ') }}
```

Now jinja2 has a `replace()` filter, which works fine on single variables, but not on lists (it splits the list into single characters). The following does the trick, but is not very elegent nor foolproof:

```
{{ favorits|join(' ===| ')|replace('|', '\|') |replace('===\|','|') }}
```

I guess I could make it *safer* by replacing `===` with a more unlikely string, but that is still not very elegant. Does any one have an idea on how to improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution is really simple: [custom filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters). In my case, this code

```
import jinja2

def list_replace(a_list,search,replace):
    new_list=[]
    for item in a_list:
        new_list.append(item.replace(search,replace))
    return new_list

templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader( searchpath="/" )
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment( loader=templateLoader )
templateEnv.filters['list_replace'] = list_replace
```

let me do this much cleaner thing in my template:

```
{{ favorits|list_replace('|', '\|')|join(' | ')}}
```

which gives the desired output.